# In my Jenkins pipeline, why am I getting 2 different execution results with seemingly similar code, i.e. one job passes and the other one fails?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing Jenkins pipeline code and have two similar Groovy files with class definitions inside them. When I run a job using one Groovy file, the job runs fine. When I run a similar job using the other Groovy file I get an error.

Please let me explain.

I have the following file structure

```
com/company/versionmgrs/
                       /VersionDirector.groovy
                       /VersionBuilder.groovy
                       /PlatformVersionBuilder.groovy
```

Here are the contents of the above Groovy files, and the corresponding `Jenkinsfile`s that instatiates them. As you can see, they're pretty similar, nothing magical. In all of them, **the class name matches the Groovy file name**. This is **important** information about this issue.

```
#VersionDirector.groovy
package com.company.versionmgrs
class VersionDirector {
  VersionDirector(def file) {
    this.file = file
  }
  def file
}

# Jenkinsfile
@Library("shared-lib") _
import com.company.versionmgrs.VersionDirector

node("build-node") {
  def vd = new VersionDirector(this)
}
```

```
#VersionBuilder.groovy
package com.company.versionmgrs
abstract class VersionBuilder {
  def file
}

#PlatformVersionBuilder.groovy
package com.company.versionmgrs
class PlatformVersionBuilder extends VersionBuilder {
  PlatformVersionBuilder(def file) {
    this.file = file
  }
}

# Jenkinsfile
@Library("shared-lib") _
import com.company.versionmgrs.PlatformVersionBuilder

node("build-node") {
  def builder = new PlatformVersionBuilder(this)
}
```

When I run the first `Jenkinsfile` that instantiates `VersionDirector`, I get no error. But when I run the second `Jenkinsfile` that instantiates `PlatformVersionBuilder`, I get the following error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/var/jenkins_home/jobs/.../PlatformVersionBuilder.groovy: 3: Invalid duplicate class definition of class com.company.versionmgrs.PlatformVersionBuilder : The source /var/jenkins_home/jobs/...PlatformVersionBuilder.groovy contains at least two definitions of the class com.company.versionmgrs.PlatformVersionBuilder.
One of the classes is an explicit generated class using the class statement, the other is a class generated from the script body based on the file name. Solutions are to change the file name or to change the class name.
 @ line 3, column 1.
   class PlatformVersionBuilder extends VersionBuilder {
   ^
```

I expect one to pass, or fail, like the other. What am I missing? TIA